# Magento - Simple Configurable Product customization

Tags: php, ajax, magento

I'm using the Simple Configurable Products extension for Magento.

I'd like to be able to change the Related products when a user changes the option in a dropdown.

Currently the extension changes the Price, short and long descriptions and the images (i.e. When the configurable dropdown option is changed, the descriptions etc change to that of the simple product).
I need to be able to pick up the following also:
Cross-sells
Upsells
Related products

Has anybody done this before, or know of way to do it?

Many thanks.

Comment: Which extension are you using currently ?

Comment: I'm using the Simple Configurable Products extension for Magento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just finished adding functionality to change URL, SKU and MSRP on option change.

It could be done in two steps. You will be needed to write some code:

1. Store the render result of `Related products` block in config variable here:

   > app/code/community/OrganicInternet/SimpleConfigurableProducts/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Type/Configurable.php
2. Inject to DOM the contents of our config variable:

   > skin/frontend/base/default/js/scp_product_extension.js

**Update**

If you already figured out how to change SKU, it will be easy for you to the same for related/upsells/crosssells products. Use `$product->getRelatedProductCollection()`, `$product->getUpSellProductCollection()` and `$product->getCrossSellProductCollection()`.

You can look at complete examples of using those here: [Fetch up-sell / related / cross-sell product programatically](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/273612/#t374989)

**Update 2**

Insert this on `line 20` in `Configurable.php`:

```
$related = $product->getRelatedProductCollection()
  ->addAttributeToSelect('required_options')
  ->addAttributeToSort('position', Varien_Db_Select::SQL_ASC)
  ->addStoreFilter();
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($related);
$related->load();

$relatedOutput = '<ul>';
foreach ($related as $item) {
  $item->setDoNotUseCategoryId(true);
  $relatedOutput .= '<li><a href="' . $item->getProductUrl() .'">'. $item->getName() .'</a></li>';
        }
$relatedOutput .= '</ul>';
$childProducts[$productId]['relatedProducts'] = $relatedOutput; // Stored to config var
```

And use `relatedProducts` as config variable.

Comment: Could you tell me how I go about storing the render result of Related Products?

Comment: Thanks. I had already tried what you've mentioned - The code just returns [Object Object] on the Product page.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. 
Perhaps I've put the $related... into the wrong place - I've added it into the Configurable.php within the foreach loop foreach ($this->getAllowProducts() as $product)

Comment: @ChristopherThrower you placed it correctly. Did you add code to print it in JS file?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't get that far. I had some PHP errors. I'll put the code back in and copy those errors here.

Comment: Here is my error: 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/lightin1/public_html/testing/app/code/community/OrganicInternet/SimpleConfigurableProducts/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Type/Configurable.php on line 30

Line 30 is here: 
$relatedOutput .= '<li><a href="' . <?php echo $item->getProductUrl() .'">'. $item->getName() .'</a></li>';

Comment: @ChristopherThrower Sorry, I've posted unchecked code. Updated my code in my answer.

Comment: Fantastic. That's pulling through the URL now - Product Name isn't coming in though. I'm going to have a play, need to find the Image & Price also :-)

Comment: Do you have Skype or something? I need a little help getting the Product Name and Image into here - Only the URL seems to work?